# shift all running process from user1 to user2

Tags: unix, permissions, id

I have presently all my process running by `user1` id on my server . Now we have a new user `user2` and we want all the process running by `user1` to run by `user2`. This is done for consistency as all other host uses `user2` What should be the things that i should follow and must do things ? Note that `user1` and `user2` both have root privileges.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/56884/change-euid-of-running-process

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if the processes can be restarted as the new user or not. Assuming the processes can be stopped and restarted, and that `user1` will actually become superfluous after the change, then it's relatively straight-forward:

1. backup (!)
2. stop all the user1 processes
3. create user2
4. (optionally) move/copy all the user1 files, just to be clear that they now belong to user2 (as necessary)
5. `chown` all the files from user1 to be user2 (as necessary)
6. be sure no script explicitly refers to `user1` by name (or `id`), or references `~user1` home directory. Make these scripts generic by using `$LOGNAME` or `$HOME` instead of the user name.

If any of the processes assume that the user has a specific id, then that is something to watch for (but unlikely to be the case). After, it's likely the case that user1 can be disabled/deleted.